# How to purge psmouse-alps-dst-0.4 driver?

Tags: 12.04, dell, touchpad, inspiron

After installing psmouse-alps-dst-0.4 driver for my Dell 5720 touchpad from here : http://www.dahetral.com/public-download I decided to uninstall it.

I removed /usr/src/psmouse-alps-dst-0.4 folder, removed psmouse from dkms and did `sudo rmmod psmouse` followed by `modprobe psmouse proto=imps`, driver works as default one but after reboot alps one is still here.

After I did it all xinput command gives me the following:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

But after restart driver is still there and xinput gives me the following:

```
 Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Mouse                                id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Where AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint is actually a device I would like to remove.

How can I fix it? I want to uninstall it completely from my system and use default driver like before. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
sudo dkms remove psmouse/alps-dst-0.4 --all
```

Comment: I've tried and got the following message: "Error! There are no instances of module: psmouse
alps-dst-0.4 located in the DKMS tree."